# C# hex to ascii

Tags: c#, string, ascii, hex

I'm trying to convert a String of hex to ASCII, using this:

```
public void ConvertHex(String hexString)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
    {
        String hs = hexString.Substring(i, i + 2);
        System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(hexString.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
    }
    String ascii = sb.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(ascii);
}
```

but I get an out or bounds exception, I'm sure its a glaring error but other code I have tried does not work either.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ASCII? Just as in Java, .NET strings are Unicode.

Answer (score 27):

This code will convert the hex string into ASCII, you can copy paste this into a class and use it without instancing

```
public static string ConvertHex(String hexString)
{
    try
    {
        string ascii = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
        {
            String hs = string.Empty;

            hs   = hexString.Substring(i,2);
            uint decval =   System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
            char character = System.Convert.ToChar(decval);
            ascii += character;

        }

        return ascii;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

**Notes**

`2` = the no. of hexString chars used to represent an ASCII character.

`System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)` = "convert the base 16 hex substrings to an unsigned 32 bit int"

Comment: *Notes* `2` = the no. of hexString chars used to represent an ASCII character.

`System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)` means "convert the base 16 hex substrings to an unsigned 32 bit int"

Answer (score 26):

There are <del>four</del> three problems here:

1. <del>Since you're incrementing `i` by 2 on each iteration, you need to terminate at `hexString.Length - 1`.</del> This doesn't actually matter; incrementing by two after the final iteration will bring the counter above the checked length regardless.
2. You're taking the wrong number of characters from `hexString`.
3. `hs` is never used.
4. You're not appending anything to `sb`.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
{
    string hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
    sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)));
}
```

Note that there's no need to qualify the types with their namespace, `System` (assuming you've referenced it at the top of the file with a `using` statement).

Comment: Thanks that's almost it, I get an Overflow exception "too large or to small", will post a fix when I have one

Comment: Where does the exception occur?

Comment: Within "sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)));"

Value was either too small or too large for a charcter :/

Comment: @Pete: Are you using `string hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);` or your original, `Substring(i, i + 2)` which takes too many characters?

Comment: @Pete: The code works for me (for well-formed hex input, that is). Can you post the complete code you're now using?

Answer (score 2):

```
String hs = hexString.Substring(i, i + 2);
System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(hexString.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
```

Do you notice you're never using `hs` ??

And that you're converting the first 2 chars over and over?

Comment: "Do you notice you're never using hs ??" yes that was a stupid mistake

"And that you're converting the first 2 chars over and over?" no I hadn't lol

Answer (score 1):

Since you are incrementing your index by 2, you need to stop your loop one-before-the-end of the length of the string.  Otherwise your last iteration of the loop will try to read characters past the end of the string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length - 1, i += 2)
```