# Hex string to plain text

Tags: c#, string, hex, ascii

I have hex representing ascii values stored in the following format.

```
// Hex reperesention of ascii string
string hexString = "48-65-6C-6C-6F-20-77-6F-72-6C-64-21-21-21";

// Could someone help fill in the blanks here? 
private string hexConverter(string hexString)
{
    string asciiCharString;

    // Convert it

    return asciiCharString;
}
```

so when called;

```
string s = hexConverter(hexString);
```

string s would contain "Hello world!!!" in this case.

Comment: The code you have shown is not an attempt at solving this. Can you edit your post to reflect your attempts thus far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# hex to ascii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613279/c-sharp-hex-to-ascii)

Comment: Split on `-`, pass the strings through hex string to byte converter, pass that byte array through `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` and you are done

Comment: Try it yourself. Hint: `string.Split`, `Convert.ToByte(string value, int fromBase)`, and `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`

Comment: @Blam no, what's relevant here is how the data was encoded. Might have been ASCII, UTF8, etc. with the given example.

Comment: @TimS. First line says "ascii"

Comment: also shows decoded version at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var convertedString = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var hex in hexString.Split('-'))
{
    var unicode = int.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    convertedString.Append((char)unicode);
}

return convertedString.ToString();
```

Comment: That may or may not be the encoding used...granted, if you only use ASCII text, you probably don't need to care.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string hexConverter(string hexString)
{
    string asciiCharString ="" ;

    var splitResult = hexString.Split('-');

    foreach (string hexChar in splitResult )
    {
        var byteChar = int.Parse(hexChar, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        asciiCharString += (char)byteChar;
    }

    return asciiCharString;
}

// Test
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hexString = "48-65-6C-6C-6F-20-77-6F-72-6C-64-21-21-21";
    string asciiString = hexConverter(hexString);

    MessageBox.Show(asciiString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets break this question down...

So you first want to break up the string based on hyphens ('-').  To do this, we would use `Split('-')`.  This yields an array of strings.

```
hexString.Split('-')
```

We then want to convert those strings into a number.  Because this is ASCII, lets convert each string into a `byte`.

```
byte.Parse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

Once we have a bunch of `byte`s, then we can convert it into a `String` using an ASCII encoder (`Encoding.ASCII.GetString()`)

So to put it all together:

```
static string hexConverter(string hexString)
{
  return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fetchBytes(hexString).ToArray());
}

static IEnumerable<byte> fetchBytes(String hexString)
{
  foreach (var value in hexString.Split('-'))
    yield return byte.Parse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
```

**Encoding**

If at a later date you decide you need **UTF-8** or something else, then all you would need to do is replace `Encoding.ASCII` with `Encoding.UTF8`, and the rest of the logic will still work.