# Win32_PhysicalMedia returns different serial number for non-admin user

Tags: c#, wmi, serial-number

I've used the following query to fetch hard disk serial number.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");
```

It returns different serial number for admin user and non-admin user as follows:

admin -    **WD-WCAYUS426947**
non-admin - **2020202057202d44435759415355323439363734**

When tried to put the non-admin serial into hex to char converter it gave **W -DCWYASU249674**, which is actually a character swap on every 2 characters.

Any idea to fetch the correct serial without manupulating the un-hexed format please?

Comment: Perhaps an Endian-ness issue?

Comment: You should check https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/623282/win32-physicalmedia-returns-incorrect-serial-number-on-vista-or-higher-when-run-as-standard-user out.

Comment: Thank you @Soner-gonel for formatting the question.

Comment: Thank you @the-dutch-man for the link. It seems like an unresolved bug from Microsoft.

Comment: @andreibarsan, may be... but I don't know why Microsoft would use different Endianess based on user authorization.

Answer (score 5):

As posted in the comments:
This seems to be an unsolved bug in Windows, although [Microsoft knows about it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/623282/win32-physicalmedia-returns-incorrect-serial-number-on-vista-or-higher-when-run-as-standard-user).

The way to solve it is to convert the hex string and swap the numbers, I wrote a method that does this for you, feel free to edit it to your needs:

```
    public static string ConvertAndSwapHex(string hex)
    {
        hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
        byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
            int j = i;
            if (j != 0)
            {
                j = (j % 2 == 1 ? j-1 : j+1);
            }
            raw[j] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw).Trim(' ', '\t', '\0');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much @thedutchman, for writing the code to convert and swap the jixed characters. I combined your code and code in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613279/c-sharp-hex-to-ascii) and created a new function like below:

```
    public static string ConvertAndSwapHex(string hexString)
    {
        var charString = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 4)
        {
            charString.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hexString.Substring(i + 2, 2), 16)));
            charString.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16)));
        }
        return charString.ToString();
    }
```

One more important thing is, as mentioned in [this microsoft forum](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/623282/win32-physicalmedia-returns-incorrect-serial-number-on-vista-or-higher-when-run-as-standard-user), using **Win32_DiskDrive** instead of **Win32_PhysicalMedia** returns jinxed serial number consistently in Win 7 for both admin and non-admin users. Even though it returns completely different things in WinXP (which we don't support for our software anymore), consistently returning the jinxed serial number is good enough for me. You know I don't have to check the length of the serial number to determine if I need to use the above ConvertAndSwap method or not.