# Line Of Hex Into ASCII

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a string of hex like

> 4100200062006C0061006E006B002000630061006E0076006100730020007200650063006F006D006D0065006E00640065006400200066006F007200200046006F007200670065002000650064006900740069006E00670020006F006E006C0079002E

Turn into ASCII and look like:

> A blank canvas recommended for Forge editing only.

The variable for the hex is collected from a file that I opened into the program, reading a specific address like so:

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));
string mapdesc = null;

for (int i = 0x1C1; i <= 0x2EF; i++)
{
    br.BaseStream.Position = i;
    mapdesc += br.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
}

richTextBox1.Text = ("" + mapdesc);
```

Now that I have the `mapdesc`, I made it print into the richtextbox, and it just looked like a line of hex. I wanted it too look like readable ASCII.

In Hex Editor, the other side reading in ANSI looks like

> A. .b.l.a.n.k. .c.a.n.v.a.s. .r.e.c.o.m.m.e.n.d.e.d. .f.o.r. .F.o.r.g.e. .e.d.i.t.i.n.g. .o.n.l.y

The dots are `00`s in the hex view, so I believe with the ASCII format, they should be nothing so that I get the readable sentence which is how the game reads it. What would I have to do to convert `mapdesc` into ASCII?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# hex to ascii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613279/c-sharp-hex-to-ascii)

Comment: The data looks like UTF16 (big endian). You should be able to read it directly with a `StreamReader` object, with the only possible complicating being the need to specify `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` in the constructor. There should be no need to convert binary to hex and then back to some other numeric or text format.

Comment: Whoa okay yeah I perfectly get you. I don't know why I was making it into hex then back to text. I didn't think that StreamReader could actually work in this case. I'll try it out and see what happens.

Comment: Judging from what others figured out it looks like you are starting your `for` loop a byte too far. Even after switching to streamreader I feel like you want to start from `0x1C1-4`, not `0x1C1`.

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. When you read text you have to use the encoding it was written with. .NET's Base Class Library supports this very well. First, find the spec for this file format to see which encoding it uses.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, the output matches the decoded output exactly, the issue is actually with the input data.

If you look closely, you will notice that ever other pair of characters is `00`, using some simple heuristics, we can determine that we have 16 bit words here, 4 hex chars.

The problem that you are facing, and the reason for the `.` characters, is that while decoding this as UTF-8, every other character will be *null*.

You have two solutions to solve this:

To continue decoding in UTF-8, remove every other *null* character from the string, all the _00_s.

Or

Decode at UTF-16

If you choose this option, you still have an issue with your data - the very first word is only 8 bits, which would cause a shift among ever other byte; to decode in UTF-16, prepend an additional *00* at the beginning of the data blob ( or start your loop one position sooner )

Comment: If you are seeking to this point in a larger blob, you could even just `x+=2` in your loop to treat the 16bit words as 8bit words, throwing out the first 8 bits.

Comment: I don't think I can get this figured out. I just don't really understand a lot of what i need to do.

Comment: Try `(int i = 0x1C0; i <= 0x2EF; i+=2)`

Comment: Now for some reason the richtextbox shows nothing but zeros.