# How to convert string of hex values into string of numbers in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have got the string like in hex view

> 33-35-34-37-36-32-31-31-32-35-32-31-32-38-38

I would like to get it like a string of corresponding values

> 354762112521288

I see it could be done like here [image]

So I am wondering which methods I have to use for it?

I try this for the first value is 33

```
 string hex = "0x33"; 
 int intValue =  Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
```

but It gives me 51 instead of 3.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Those are hex values of characters representing digits (byte)'3' = 0x33. To get a char from a byte value like this, do `char c = (char)byteValue`.

Comment: `0x33` hex value means `51` in decimal system

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Would you mind to provide C# code please?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks! Would u mind to give a couple of C# lines please?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, exactly.

Comment: @DmitryBoyko I think Sweeper was hoping you'd tell him which of the two alternatives he mentioned apply :)

Comment: @Sweeper It is int[] containing 33, 35, 34, 37, 36, 32, 31, 31, 32, 35, 32, 31, 32

Comment: I found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613279/c-sharp-hex-to-ascii
Thank you!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724862/converting-from-hex-to-string

Comment: `int[] numbers = { 33, 35, 34, 37, 36, 32, 31, 31, 32, 35, 32, 31, 32, 38, 38 }; int[] converted = numbers.Select(number => Convert.ToInt32(number.ToString(), 16) - '0').ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

I think,
The hex value for 3 is "3"
"0x33" is 51 in decimal

Comment: Please provide C# code, thank you!

Comment: @DmitryBoyko your code is correct

Comment: Oh, gerat! So... How to convert 51 to 3 then?

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/convert-integer-to-hexadecimal-and-back-again